# How can I check whether a JSON Object key has a certain value

Tags: jquery, json

How can I check whether a JSON object key has a certain value?

I use PHP to fetch data and json_encode to get the output in JSON. Afterwards I use Ajax to append the result into a div.

What I'm trying to achieve is if a certain key has a certain value - then do group them together: something like this:

```
If Key_Status = "value_Solved" {
// do something
} else If Key_Status = "value_Not_Solved" { {
// do something else
};
```

I do not receive any errors nor output.

This is what I have achieved so far:

```
                        $.ajax({
                    url: "api-json.php?api",
                data: {id: idGet},
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if (json) {
                            $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
                                //now json variable contains data in obj format
                                //let's display a few items
                                var id = obj.task.id;
                                var customer = obj.task.customer;
                                var task = obj.task.task;
                                var status = function(key, val) {
                                    var elm = obj.task.status;
                                    if ( elm == 'Solved' ) {
                                        $("#"+id).css("background", "blue");
                                        console.log("#"+id);
                                    }
                                };
                                var solver = obj.task.solver;
                                var issuer = obj.task.issuer;
                                var added = obj.task.added;
                                var label = obj.task.label;

                                $('#results')
                                .append(" <div class='board-list-box' id='" + id + "'> <a class='board-list-box-edit'><span class='edit'></span><span class='update'></span><span class='delete'></span><span class='screen-reader-text'>Edit</span></a>  <label class='board-list-box-label " + label + "'></label>  <p class='board-list-box-text'> " + task + "</p>  <span class='board-list-box-info'>" + added + "</span> </div>");
                            });
                        } else {
                            $('#results').html("<p class='error'>" + json + " tasks to do </p>");
                        }
                    }           
                });
```

My JSON OUTPUT is like this:

```
[
    {
    "task": {
        "id": "537",
        "task": "Test 1",
        "description": "",
        "customer": "",
        "issuer": "",
        "solver": "",
        "label": "green",
        "status": "Not started",
        "deadline": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "added": "16-01-24 06:20:55"
    },
    "comments": "comments",
    "labels": "labels"
},
{
    "task": {
        "id": "538",
        "task": "Test 2",
        "description": "",
        "customer": "",
        "issuer": "",
        "solver": "",
        "label": "green",
        "status": "Not started",
        "deadline": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "added": "16-01-24 06:20:58"
    },
    "comments": "comments",
    "labels": "labels"
}
```

]

Comment: Your approach is valid (even though it's a JS object, not a JSON), do you have an error somewhere?

Comment: Provide better explanation of problem. You aren't using the arguments passed into that function and other variables appear from nowhere

Comment: I don't get any return. I've updated my code. Look above. This is how I extract

Comment: You aren't calling the function in that `each` loop. You are only declaring the function. Explain in words what you want to accomplish

Comment: I do call it. I append the result to a div afterwards using var status. What I want to achieve is IF obj.task.status = Solved { do something ..}. That I need to be used by var status;

Comment: Then show all the relevant code. This whole question is not well constructed. Full problem description is missing and code is incomplete and doesn't show where you call this function or explain what is or isn't working.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for that. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited Answer:**

Let's refer the below method:

```
function CheckTasks() {
  var Tasks = '[{ "task": { "id": "537", "task": "Test 1", "description": "", "customer": "", "issuer": "", "solver": "", "label": "green", "status": "Not started", "deadline": "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "added": "16-01-24 06:20:55" }, "comments": "comments", "labels": "labels" }, { "task": { "id": "538", "task": "Test 2", "description": "", "customer": "", "issuer": "", "solver": "", "label": "green", "status": "Not started", "deadline": "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "added": "16-01-24 06:20:58" }, "comments": "comments", "labels": "labels" }]';

  var obj = JSON.parse(Tasks);
  var groupedTasks=[];  // Array which will have the Task IDs if the Status is Not started.

  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      //alert(obj[key].task.status); // To access the Status of a Task

      if (obj[key].task.status == "Not started") {
        groupedTasks.push(obj[key].task.id);  // Push the Task ID in the array.
      }
    }
  }
  alert(groupedTasks) ;  // The Grouped Tasks with Status as Not started will be available in this Array.
}
```

The `JSON.parse()` method parses a string as JSON.

`key` refers to the number of tasks present. We have 2 tasks(537 & 538).

The `hasOwnProperty()` method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified `property`.

In the above code, we iterate through each `key` (tasks) and check whether it has a `property` or not. If it has a `property`, then get the `value` using `obj[key].task.status`.

An array `groupedTasks` is created and if the status is Not started, the IDs of those tasks are added(pushed) into this array.

Please refer this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyv5cq66/4/) link and check the results.

Comment: Could you explain me how to use it afterwards? I am knew at this and I want to learn the proper approach.

Comment: @Rorabih, I have given the sample code. data[key] will have all the objects. To access each object, you have to use data[key].OBJECTNAME (which you had given in your code). Please elaborate your requirement and accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: I'm new at this so please bear with me. I don't get the syntax nor the explanation you just gave. What is the OBJECTNAME and hasOwnPropery in this case (correspond to my question above). What I wanted to achieve is to look in my JSON for every Task which has the same **status (a key in my JSON)** and then group them together in a div. Hope you understand.

Comment: @Rorabih, I had mentioned wrongly as OBJECTNAME. It should be PROPERTY. I have taken your example and updated the answer with more details. Please check and give your feedback.

Comment: That was a very good explanation! Thank you @BalaSakthis! One last thing. How can I group the various "task" (from JSON) together dependent on status?

Comment: @Rorabih, I have updated the answer based on your new requirements. I have modifed the JSFiddle code also. You can also update this new requirement in the question as it will help the future readers! Please check and accept.

Comment: sorry for my late late answer. This is accepted as a solution to my issue. I will update my question so that the new requirements also becomes useful to others with same issue/challenge. Again - thank you for your help!

Comment: @Rorabih, Glad to hear that my answer helped you.